# Is there a way of changing the shape of the hitboxes for HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a project, and inside a have a diamond. It is shaped like this:[image]

However, you can click anywhere in the bounding box to activate it. This is annoying because if you put lots together, they will activate the bounding box of the one created first, as its box is overlapping the other one.

What I am looking for is a simple function to change its shape, be that in CSS or JS, or a similar workaround.

Comment: Use `svg` to achieve this, it is much easier to respect bounding boxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do this with `clip-path`

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  /* to create the borders*/
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top    left ,transparent 49%,#000 50%) top    left,
    linear-gradient(to top    right,transparent 49%,#000 50%) top    right,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left ,transparent 49%,#000 50%) bottom left,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,#000 50%) bottom right;
  background-size:calc(50% + 5px) calc(50% + 3px); /* control the border thickness here */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color:red;
  
  clip-path:polygon(50% 0,100% 50%,50% 100%,0 50%);
}
.box:hover {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="margin:50px 0 0 -100px"></div>
<div class="box" style="margin:0 0 0 -100px"></div>
```